# WPF Xaml Parse Exception unhandled

Tags: wpf, xaml, parsing, exception, unhandled

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'JustSnap.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'.

If I click view details:

```
{System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified module could not be found
   at JustSnap.UserActivityHook.Start(Boolean InstallKeyboardHook) in c:\Users\Tagon\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\JustSnap\JustSnap\UserActivityHook.cs:line 67
   at JustSnap.UserActivityHook.Start() in c:\Users\Tagon\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\JustSnap\JustSnap\UserActivityHook.cs:line 42
   at JustSnap.UserActivityHook..ctor() in c:\Users\Tagon\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\JustSnap\JustSnap\UserActivityHook.cs:line 38
   at JustSnap.MainWindow..ctor() in c:\Users\Tagon\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\JustSnap\JustSnap\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 29}
```

How can I find my problem and resolve it ?
What you need to know to help me?

Regards,
Tagon

**EDIT**

```
public void Start(bool InstallKeyboardHook)
        {
            if (hKeyboardHook == 0 && InstallKeyboardHook)
            {
                KeyboardHookProcedure = new HookProc(KeyboardHookProc);
                hKeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(
                    WH_KEYBOARD_LL,
                    KeyboardHookProcedure,
                    Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(
                    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0]),
                    0);
                if (hKeyboardHook == 0)
                {
                    int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    Stop(true, false);
                    throw new Win32Exception(errorCode);
                }
            }
        }

public void Stop(bool UninstallKeyboardHook, bool ThrowExceptions)
        {
            if (hKeyboardHook != 0 && UninstallKeyboardHook)
            {
                int retKeyboard = UnhookWindowsHookEx(hKeyboardHook);
                hKeyboardHook = 0;
                if (retKeyboard == 0 && ThrowExceptions)
                {
                    int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    throw new Win32Exception(errorCode);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: what's on line 67 of UserActivityHook.cs

Comment: look for any non existent static resources in your xaml

Comment: Line 38: Start();
Line 42: {
Line 67: Stop(true, false);

Line 29 in MainWindow.xaml.cs:
actHook = new UserActivityHook();

On the start and stop function working whole program

Comment: Post code for Start and Stop; that may give some idea.

Comment: Similar problem discussed [here](http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/workitem/183). Try changing `Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0])` to `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.BaseAddress`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing:

```
Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0])
```

to:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.BaseAddress
```

Thats helped me :))